# How do I simply access the values of an "edge sequence" igraph object?

Tags: r, igraph

I want to access the IDs of vertices that are connected from vertex u in graph g.

I use the command `E(g)[from(u)]`. This generates the following output:

`Edge sequence:`

`[9814] 122 ->  24`

`[9815] 122 -> 178`

`[9816] 122 -> 124`

How do I access the values 24, 178, and 124?

I realise this may be a simple command, but I cannot find out how to do it anywhere in the documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe simplest is to use the `neighbors()` function in the first place:

```
neighbors(g, u, mode="out")
```

If you really want to do it from an edge sequence, then:

```
V(g)[ to(E(g)[from(u)]) ]
```

See

http://igraph.org/r/doc/structure.info.html
http://igraph.org/r/doc/graph.structure.html
http://igraph.org/r/doc/iterators.html